# Gitlab run different deploment scripts on merge depending on Labels

Tags: gitlab-ci

How can I run different CI deployment scripts on merge to master depending on the labels attached to the merge request?

I have a repository from which I build different versions of my software. I keep it in one repository as the systems share 90% of the code but there are differences that defitively need code modifications. On merge requests all versions are buildt and a suite of tests is run. Usually I want to deploy on accepting the merge request.

As not always the changes are relevant for all systems I would like to attach labels to the merge request that decide which deployments scripts are run on accepting the merge request. I already tried to automatically decide on the changed code parts but this is not possible as often I expand a shared library but this is only relevant for one of the systems.

I am aware of variables but I don't know how to apply them on merge accept in YML like this

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
      ...
  only:
    - master
```

Update on strategy:

As CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS is not available with only:master I will try to do a beta deployment depending on merge request labels in only:merge-request. In only:master I will deploy the betas that have changed. This most likely will fit my needs. I will add it as a solution once it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it this way:

My YML script has three stages:

```
stages:
  - buildtest
  - createbeta
  - deploy

buildtest:
  stage: buildtest
  script:
  -  ... run unit tests
  -  ... build all systems
  -  ... run scripted tests on all systems
  only:
    refs:
    - merge_requests

createbeta:
  stage: createbeta
  script:
  - ... run setup and update package creation with parameter $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS
  - ... run update package tests with parameter $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS
  - ... run beta deployment scripts with parameter $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS (see text)
  only:
    refs:
    - merge_requests

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - ... run production deployment scripts (see text)
  only:
    refs:
    - master
```

The first stages are run on merge request creation.

- As changes to shared libraries might affect all systems all builds and tests are run in stage "buildtest".
- The scripts in stage "createbeta" check for existance of the merge request label for the corresponding system and are skipped if the system is not involved by the labels.
- The script for beta deployment creates a signal file "deploy_me" in the beta folder (important) if it runs
- When the request is merged the deployment script runs in stage "deploy". It checks for the existance of the "deploy_me" file and only deploys and informs via mail if the file exists.

This way I can easily decide which system I want to deploy by applying a labes to the merge request. I can thorowly test the new feature with the beta version and make sure that changes do not break the other systems as unittests and system tests are run for all systems.

As the GitLab runner runs in a Windows environment (yes, this makes sense as I work with Delphi) here is the way I find the system label in a Windows cmd file for those who are interested. I use %* as the labels are separated by spaces and treated as individual command line parameters.

```
echo %* | findstr /i /c:"MyCoolSystem" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto runit
rem If the label is not supplied with the merge request, do nothing
goto ok
:runit
... content
:ok
```

Perhaps this helps someone with a similar environment and similar workflow.